# Can ES6 file be used with custom npx command

Tags: es6-modules, npx

Created a project with custom npx command

```
"bin": {"myCommand": "./bin/myJsFile.js"}
```

js file is in ES6 and use the import statement to import a file say importFile written in ES6.

I deploy the command locally using `npm i -g`

when I try to run it locally using `npx`.

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\project\src\importFile ' imported from C:\project\src\bin\myJsFile.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:416:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:932:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1044:11)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:422:30)
```